# Moving folders in Linux inconsistency

Tags: command-line, shell, mv

I have a shell script that deploy an application to a staging server. However, one of the application's directory needs to be backed up and restored after the deployment (so it is not overwritten). I manage to backup the directory, but the restore part does not behave as expected. Basically, here are the two lines in the shell script :

```
...
# backup user avatars
mv vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/users/ ~/tmp/img-users.BAK/ &> /dev/null

...
# restore user avatars
mv ~/tmp/img-users.BAK/ vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/users/ &> /dev/null
```

The problem is that the first command creates the correct folder under `~/tmp/`, but the second command creates `vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/users/img-users.BAK/`, which is not good.

The expected behaviour would be that `img-users.BAK` would move all files back, overwritting any files in the destination folder, leaving any other files untouched.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

**Note**: recursivity is not necessary as there are no directory under that path.

### ** Edit **

#### Step 1 : backup directory

**Before**

```
./vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/
  ./users/
    ./1.png
    ./14.png
    ./README
    ...
./tmp/
  <empty>
```

**After**

```
./vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/
   <empty>
 ./tmp/
   ./img-users.BAK/
    ./1.png
    ./14.png
    ./README
    ...
```

Everything is as expected.

#### Step 2 : Restore directory

**Before**

```
./vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/
  ./users/
    ./1.png
    ./3.png
    ./README
    ...
./tmp/
  ./img-users.BAK/
    ./1.png
    ./14.png
    ./README
    ...
```

**After** *(actual)*

```
./vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/
  ./users/
    ./img-users.BAK/
      ./1.png
      ./14.png
      ./README
      ...
    ./3.png
    ./1.png
    ./README
    ...
./tmp/
  <empty>
```

**After** *(expected)*

```
./vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/
  ./users/
    ./1.png        <-- overwritten
    ./14.png
    ./3.png
    ./README       <-- overwritten
    ...
./tmp/
  <empty>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands you issued are doing exactly the right thing, namely, moving **directories**.  If you need to move or copy the **files** in the `img/users` directory back, then do that explictly:

```
mv -f ~/tmp/img-users.BAK/* vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/users/
```

Note that I included the `-f` which will force overwrite without asking.  Be careful.  Also, not sure why you want to throw away STDOUT, so I left that off too.

Comment: Had to add `rm -Rf ~/tmp/img-users.BAK` after moving the files, though. But this works. Chose this because of the `-f` flag, too.

Comment: Probably don't want the `-Rf`, just `rmdir`, under the theory that the directory should be empty (ignoring dot files) after the `mv` completed.  Moreover, if the `mv` failed, you probably **really** don't want to recursively remove the temp dir and it's contents, which are still useful, presumably.

Comment: You would be right, however if the process fail, I just revert the VM to the previous snapshot (part of the script), as the `mv` and `rm` commands are being executed through SSH. I didn't mention this as it has nothing to do with the question here.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the first case, the destination does not exists, and already exists in the second.

```
mv ~/tmp/img-users.BAK/ vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/users/
```

The second command moves all but the last files into the last directory, so you need to list the all files to move. You can do that with globbing:

```
mv ~/tmp/img-users.BAK/* vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/users/
```

As an (important) side note, you should avoid to have a `/` at the end of the source directory. It can have very odd side effects, and is not of much use anyway:

From `pinfo mv`:

```
**Warning**: Avoid specifying a source name with a trailing slash,
when it might be a symlink to a directory.  Otherwise, `mv' may do
something very surprising, since its behavior depends on the underlying
rename system call.  On a system with a modern Linux-based kernel, it
fails with `errno=ENOTDIR'.  However, on other systems (at least
FreeBSD 6.1 and Solaris 10) it silently renames not the symlink but
rather the directory referenced by the symlink.
```

Comment: Do you mean "in the first case, the destination does not exists, and does in the second", instead?

Comment: You move `.../users` into `~/tmp/img-users.BAK/`, so you have `~/tmp/img-users.BAK/users`, right? And later, you want the files in `~/tmp/img-users.BAK/users` back in the other `.../users`, right? Yes, it's very unclear which dest exist or not, depends on perspective...

Comment: You are right with the "exists" thing. But, I tried and ended up with `img/users/users`, not `img/users/img-users.BAK`. Now I'm confused.

Comment: See the edit :)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - chances are that you issued your experiment twice and moved a directory into a previously existing /tmp/img-users.BAK directory.

Answer (score 0):

If the in-between stage between backup and restore is re-creating the `users` directory (as seems to be the case), then to restore it, you'll want to either re-name individual files (as has been shown in previous answers, though I would argue that may not be what you want), or, in the `restore` script, remove the `users` directory before moving it back into place, so, with `backup` staying the same (except to take in the trailing-slash issue mentioned in the answer by Volker Siegel:

```
...
# backup user avatars
mv vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/users ~/tmp/img-users.BAK
```

You would add a command to `restore`, like:

```
...
# restore user avatars
rm -rf vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/users
mv ~/tmp/img-users.BAK vitex/app/modules/users/pub/img/users
```

I've also removed the redirection to `/dev/null`, because I think in the typical case you won't need it (mv will be silent), whereas if something weird goes on, you'll get the error messages that could be useful in figuring out what happened.